# How to find the limit of f(x)/g(x) from graphs when they're both equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble finding a limit from the following two graphs:

[Graphs of f(x) and g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd86Z.jpg)

I need to find the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from the left. As you can see, both values are equal to zero, making the limit equal to $0/0$ which is undefined. If the equations were given, we can manipulate them to get a different answer. However, we are only given the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be able to apply L'Hospital's rule

Comment: I don't think you can do much without the expressions ... Do you know about their derivatives?

Comment: Near to but a little less than $x=3$ the graph of $y=f(x)$ has roughly the behavior of $y=0$ (assuming the turning point is exactly at $x=3)$ and the graph of $y=g(x)$ has roughly the behavior of $y = x - 3.$ Now consider what the behavior of $\frac{0}{x-3}$ is for values of $x$ just a little less than $3.$

Comment: The graphs indicate that $f'(3)=0$ and $g'_-(3)>0$ (where the latter is the left derivative). L'Hospital's rule applies.